# Cannot Open Shared Object cygmpfr-1.dll

Tags: c, cygwin, shared-objects

I'm testing CeGCC, that is a gcc built to cross-compile applications to Windows CE devices. As everyone do to test compilers, I've done a Hello World program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!");
  return 0;
}
```

As I'm using Windows now(because this is my other laptop), I'm using Cygwin. But when I tried to compile I got some errors, as you can see on the terminal log:

> C:\Dev\WinCE\Test>arm-mingw32ce-gcc test.c
>   /opt/mingw32ce/libexec/gcc/arm-mingw32ce/4.4.0/cc1.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygmpfr-1.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> C:\Dev\WinCE\Test>

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Install libmpfr1 package in cygwin.

Surranó