# how to compile c++ files with cygwin on windows 7

Tags: c++, dll, cygwin

I have installed cygwin. But when I try to compile a c++ file it gives the following error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.3.4/cc1plus.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygmpfr-1.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I checked in the lib folder there is no library with the name `cygmpfr-1.dll`. So is it that I have to put that dll in the lib folder. I have tried to search for the dll but could not find this dll so that i can download. I am just a beginner in C++. I have tried to setup cygwin support in netbeans as well, but there also if I try to run the sample files given, it throws the above error.

Can anybody give me a clue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot Open Shared Object cygmpfr-1.dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614020/cannot-open-shared-object-cygmpfr-1-dll)

Comment: Yes it seems to be duplicate but i have added libmpfr1 . But now another error comes something like  /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.3.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++

Comment: I agree with Cheeso. Why on earth are you trying to compile for cygwin when you're clearly a beginner. It's not trivial. You should install a copy of Kubuntu. Learning C++ on linux is extremely easier than on windows. Also, what does this have to do with gdb, netbeans? And is this C or C++? If it's C++ why are you using gcc?

Comment: Looks like you're compiling C++ - should the "C" tag be removed?  Additionally, which compiler are you using?  What command line?

Comment: All i was trying was to configure C++ support in Netbeans, so that it is easy to write, compile and execute programs just like i do for java.I have downloaded everything form the cygwin site and set the paths and i get to see the version numbers of c and c++ compiler, And when i try to compile any C or C++ program the error is the same. There is no difference. Anyways i have installed Visual C++ , so thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: I also have cygwin for windows which provides a linux like API, if I try to complie through that, it gives the same error. The compiler is  gcc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the **gcc4-g++** package via http://cygwin.com/setup.exe
You only have gcc4 installed.

This will also install your missing dependencies.

Comment: gcc4*- packages are obsolete. Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105574/no-gcc4-in-cygwins-package-list

Answer (score 0):

If you're a beginner in C/C++, and you're running Windows, then why not take the simple route and get [Visual-C++ Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/), a free IDE from Microsoft for Windows.

It provides a GUI IDE (Integrated Development Environment), but if you prefer a text editor and command-line tools (compilers, debuggers, etc) those are available to you also, if you install Visual-C++ Express.

There are also [tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualc/default.aspx) and lessons to get you started.

---

On the other hand, if you really wanna focus on C++ on Linux, then you should probably uninstall Windows 7 right now.

Comment: Indeed - C and even C++ development is painful on windows. (Visual Studio still only supports C89!! Doesn't even have stdtypes.h!)  If you want to learn C and C++ in an "ideal" environment, go with Linux. (There's a reason why .NET is so popular in windows, it's an awesome facade over win32).

Comment: It is an answer - the person asking the question is clearly stuck, and this is, at least until the question is clarified, one of the best suggestions that can be made.
(Knowing the language one is working with is a pre-requisite for compiling code using Cygwin - originally the question was related to netbeans!)

Comment: I don't agree that C/C++ development is painful on Windows, at least no more painful than developing C/C++ on any platform. It works, it's straightforward, you can use a GUI or makefiles, there are debuggers and linkers and dependency checkers and so on. It works. Rather than saying "it's painful", I'd say, if you're going to develop C/C++ on Windows, and you're a beginner, the best place to start is with Visual-C++ Express.

Comment: Cheeso: While it works, I'm not sure if I'd be convinced that it's "straightforward".  Using MFC or any of the win32-based API's tend to encourage C-like-C++, which is painful.  Also, in this day and age, do we really need incompatible libc's for each different version of visual studio?  Every .dll that possibly links into our application "should" use the exact same libc, it's a nightmare!  Finally, if the OP is indeed asking about C, rather than C++, then it *is* painful because it's ancient! It still only supports C89, no C99 at all!

Comment: If he's learning C and C++, then he need not concern himself with MFC or any  of the other Windows-specific packages.  He can do native C/C++ code in a straightforward manner. As for the libc versioning issue, it HAS been a nightmare, but there is a straightforward answer there.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems and I am no beginner.  Try using the cygwin installer, and searching it for all versions of gmp.  There generally are 32bit and 64 bit versions.  Check everything you see and update your installation.  Hope this helps.  Some of these dll's you can find on the internet, but not the one you are looking for.