# No gcc4 in Cygwin's package list

Tags: gcc, cygwin

I had to use NS-2 on Windows. Thus, I've installed Cygwin and downloaded NS-2 source and run `./install` then it says

```
Cygwin detected
Note: Cygwin install is still considered EXPERIMENTAL

Checking Cygwin version is >= 1.7.1... 1.7.27 (should be ok)
Checking filesystems are mounted as UNIX filetype... yes
Checking default mode is binmode... yes
Checking legitimate login name... ok
Checking legitimate path name... ok
Checking for gcc4... NO!
```

There are packages in Cygwin that seem to be related to gcc4

```
cygwin64-gcc
gcc
mingw-gcc
mingw64-*-gcc
```

And all of them have versions >= 4.x

And there are no packages named `*gcc4*`

Comment: So which of them have you tried installing?

Comment: I've installed all of them containing characters 'gcc' but there is no 'gcc4'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `gcc4-*` packages are obsolete; `gcc-*` now provides version 4.x of the compiler.  You'll need to patch this script to check e.g. `gcc -dumpversion` instead of a specific package name.

Comment: You mean that the problem will be solved if I modify `install` script in some way to check `gcc` instead `gcc4` ?

Comment: Well, I'm not a such pro, I've just removed that check procedures. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I've performed the commands below in CygWin and managed to fix the issue.

```
cd /bin
ln -s gcc.exe gcc-4
ln -s gcc.exe gcc-3
ln -s gcc.exe 'g++-4'
```

Answer (score -1):

gcc is backwards compatible, so simlinking gcc-4 to gcc and g++ to g++-4 will get you exactly what you need.